# Magento rest api get customer by email id

Tags: php, rest, magento, oauth, magento-1.7

I am using the magento OAuth to get the customer information. Right now i am able to get customer list and customer information by "customerId" .  [Reference link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html)

Can i get the customer information by email id ?

Answer (score 3):

I think I just figured it out...

```
GET /api/rest/customers/?filter[0][attribute]=email&filter[0][in][0]=my.email@address.de HTTP/1.1
```

This filters my customers using the email address submitted. Further information about GET-Request filtering you can find here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/get_filters.html